# Flutter: How to add a Listview under a scrollable Map

Tags: list, flutter, openstreetmap

i have a problem. I want to create a list under the map that i created. The map is working, but if i want to put a list under the map i get some fails. This is an OpenStreetMap not Google Maps, cause i need it for my project. i just need advise how i can put a 'list' or a Text with icons under the map.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocation/geolocation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  /*create Controller for map
   *MapController provides map properties and allows map movement
  */
  MapController controller = new MapController();

  //ask for permission to use the device's gps
  getPermission() async {
    final GeolocationResult result =
    await Geolocation.requestLocationPermission(
        permission: const LocationPermission(
          //permission settings for android and ios
            android: LocationPermissionAndroid.fine,
            ios: LocationPermissionIOS.always));
    return result;
  }

  /*if permission is granted, request current location (high accuracy)
   *return coordinates of current location (Position)
   */
  getLocation() {
    return getPermission().then((result) async {
      if (result.isSuccessful) {
        final coords =
        await Geolocation.currentLocation(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
        return coords;
      }
    });
  }

  //view map, move to current lat/long and zoom
  buildMap() {
    getLocation().then((response) {
      response.listen((value) {
        if (value.isSuccessful) {
          controller.move(
              new LatLng(value.location.latitude, value.location.longitude),
              17.0);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  //Application view
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child:Container(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 111, 118, 0.9),
          child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
            children: <Widget>[
            Text('Menü',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),),

            ListTile(
              title: Text('LogIn', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),),
              leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white,),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app.
                // ...
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Ort hinzufügen', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),),
              leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white,),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app.
                // ...
              },
            ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Hilfe', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),),
                leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white,),
                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app.
                  // ...
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Einstellungen', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),),
                leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white,),
                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app.
                  // ...
                },
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('GeoGuide'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 111, 118, 0.8),

      ),
      //create new FlutterMap
      body: new Container(
        width: 420,
        height: 300,
              child: new FlutterMap(
                mapController: controller,
                //center: current location
                options: new MapOptions(center: buildMap(), minZoom: 15.0),
                layers: [
                  //implement osm-template
                  new TileLayerOptions(
                      urlTemplate:
                      "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                ]),
          ),      
    );
  }
}
```